# Exclude Posts of a Term From a Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Post type is Press. 
Taxonomy is Press Types (slug=presstype). 
Term is Press Releases (slug=release).

I simply want to add some PHP to my functions file that will exclude any posts termed "release" from the ordinary Wordpress custom post type loop for press (e.g. mydomain.com/press) but *not* from other custom loops in which press might be included.

Searched SO many different ways but can't really find a working solution. Anyone know the simplest code for functions.php that will do this?

Comment: Please edit your question to make more clear what your input is, what your desired output is and what you have tried so far to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried simply removing the term `release` with `pre_get_posts`? For semantic clarity you can wrap it with the [`is_post_type_archive()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive) function. So only on the `/press` page (Press Archive), a [`tax_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) parameter is set to *exclude* any posts with the term slug `release`.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'remove_release_from_press' );
function remove_release_from_press( $query ) {
    if( is_post_type_archive( 'press' ) ){
        $tax_query = array([
            'taxonomy' => 'presstype',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'release',
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ]);
        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}
```

Comment: XHYNK, that's crazy effective. Thank you :)